# C++ decrypt on download

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

I want to decrypt a file as I am downloading it, so I do not have to download the file fully, and then read it again to decrypt it. For downloading files I am using a Qt class and the main interesting part is done here:

```
void HttpFileDownloader::OnHttpReadyRead()
{
    if (m_downloadfile && !m_downloadRequestAborted)
    {
        QByteArray recvd_data = m_netreply->readAll();
        // do encryption here
        m_downloadfile->write(recvd_data);
        m_hash_builder->addData(recvd_data);
    }
}
```

For decrypting/encrypting files I want to use an symmetric encryption algorithm (AES-256-CBC) from the OpenSSL library. I found this article with an example implementation: https://medium.com/@amit.kulkarni/encrypting-decrypting-a-file-using-openssl-evp-b26e0e4d28d4

Is this a robust approach for decrypting on the fly for files around 200MB?

Comment: In the case of CBC you will need to carry the decryption context around

Comment: Yes, that would require a member variable of some sort, which I dont like really.

Comment: Also note that AES works on 16-byte blocks. If your HTTP read returns 163 bytes (=10 blocks + 3 loose bytes), you will not be able to decrypt the last block and the rest of your file will be corrupted.

Comment: But the length of the encrypted file has to be divisible by 16 always, or not? So this would only be a problem in case of corruption?

Comment: Oh, is this connected to the `finished` signal of your network reply? then that should be fine.

Comment: No its connected to the signal emited whenever there is new bytes incoming, so they are not necessarily divisible by 16. the point of failure I see for this is this line:
        ```EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, out_buf, &out_len, in_buf, num_bytes_read)``` but I can not find any docs on what happens when the block size is not correct. If that is an issue I would push the received bytes in a global buffer and only operate on them while there are still entire blocks.